# 'Unfold' in Swift's Combine Framework

Tags: swift, functional-programming, reactive, combine

I'm looking for a method that allows you to react upon the previous output to create a new stream.

It would be similar to [scan](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/zip/scan(_:_:)), but rather than returning an output, it would return another publisher that publishes the next result.

Here's something similar to the scan example:

```
func next(x: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int?, Never> {
    return Future { x < 5 ? $0(.success(x + 1)) : $0(.success(nil)) }
}

next(0)
    .fold { x != nil ? next(x) : nil }
    .collect()
// Yields [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Something more real:

```
paginated(0)
    .fold(limit: 100) { $0.index < $0.total ? paginated($0.index + 1) : nil  }
    .collect()
// Yields all pages as an array
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for an "unfold" operation. Having a function that accepts some state and produces output + next state, it can produce a sequence of outputs from a single state.

Details here: https://nabilhassein.github.io/blog/unfold/

No idea how to do it in Swift though.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Sounds more like the opposite of a fold.

Comment: Interestingly, Swift seems to have an implementation for it in classic sequences: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unfoldsequence

But as far as I can see, no Combine implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing something I'm more or less happy with for now myself:

```
func unfold(limit: Int = -1, _ fun: @escaping (Output) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>?) -> Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>, AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>> {
    flatMap { value -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> in
        let justPublisher = Just(value).mapError { $0 as! Failure }
        
        guard limit != 0, let publisher = fun(value) else {
            return justPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        return justPublisher.append(publisher.fold(limit: limit - 1, fun)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

I'm very open to suggestions on variant approaches though!